# Local NSNotification fire date need to set after 12 hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsnotificationcenter

How to set my localNotifications fire date property exactly after 12 hours?
my code snippet is as below,

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 if (localNotif == nil)
     return;
 localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date]; // how to set after 12 hours
 localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 localNotif.fireDate =[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*12]
```

time interval is in seconds